# Auto increment in active android

Tags: android, database, activeandroid

I tried to use active android, i have a  doubt about how could i achieve a auto-increment field  in a table?

In their documentation they have provided a code like this

```
Item item = new Item();
item.remoteId = 1;
item.category = restaurants;
item.name = "Outback Steakhouse";
item.save();
```

Can we make the remoteId field auto-increment?

Answer (score 1):

In sqlite you should use Autoincrement tag in create table: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

In other cases use methods like getPrev(), getNext(), etc.

Comment: https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/ActiveAndroid-Guide
this is the library but here not mentioned how to autoincrement.

Comment: @luttuandroid please provide the code where you want use items from this libs